# Contagem de compartilhamento e curtidas do facebook no loop do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loop, facebook

Seguinte estou tentando colocar só uma contagem dos compartilhamento que tive no Facebook no *loop* do meu tema. Para isso achei a seguinte função e tentei modifica-la para minha necessidade.

Segue a função:

```
function ia_fb_count($url_post) {
//Get the transient value from database
$fbcount = get_transient( 'fblcount' );
    if ( empty( $fbcount ) ){
        //If no value stored, get the like count
       $file = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=$url_post");
            $jd = json_decode($file);
            $fbcount = number_format($jd->{'shares'});

        // Set the facebook likes transient value for 24 Hours
        set_transient('fblcount', $fbcount, 60*60*24 );
        // Also, return it at the same time
        return $fbcount;
    } else {
        // Transient Value is present, return it
        return $fbcount;
    }
}
```

Como eu chamo a função no meu tema:

```
<?php
   $url_post = the_permalink(); 
   echo ia_fb_count($url_post);
?>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 mais no meu tema não está aparecendo as contagem do shared e sim o link da url.. veja na imagem: http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_url_faceboo.jpg preciso que apareça só a contagem de shared do facebook

Comment: @Qmechanic73 continua não chamando só a numeração e sim a url toda http://localhost/wordpress/?p=368851,588 .. acho que essa função não está pegando o link passando pelo o thema.. no $url_post .. só não estou sabendo e fazer como!

Comment: Fazendo isso manualmente retorna algum resultado?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 está retornando esse erro: http://localhost/wordpress/?p=36885
Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\brasilseries\functions.php on line 135

Comment: Deve ser porque você está formulando errado a url, veja se desse [**jeito**](http://pastebin.com/sT3jKTAH) funciona.

Answer (score 1):

A função que você está usando para pegar o permalink está errada. Essa função retorna o link com a tag html: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">permalink</a>`. É para imprimir o permalink e não para buscar a URL. No seu código deve utilizar a função [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

Como você está chamado essa função pelo tema, é importante buscar o ID do post. Assim você pode chamá-la fora do loop também.

```
<?php
   global $post;
   $url_post = get_permalink($post->ID); 
   echo ia_fb_count($url_post);
?>
```

Por fim, se você está testando em um localhost o graph api vai retornar um erro porque ele não consegue achar a URL.